# Can I return a CRecordset object from a function?

Tags: c++, mfc, odbc, recordset

I have my project in MFC vc++. I have my UI and business logic layer separated from the data access layer.
I have a function which selects some data from the database in to a CRecordset object. this select query is handled in the data access layer. When I try to return the record set (to use the data to construct a table in UI) I get an error.

I tried this:

```
CRecordset COrderSearch::ExecuteSqlQuery(CString query)
{
CString sqlQuery;
CRecordset records;
CDatabase database;
sqlQuery = L"SELECT * FROM USers";
SetConnectionStr(connectionString);  //set the connection string
ConnectToDatabase();  //database.open()     
records.m_pDatabase = &database;
records.Open(CRecordset::dynaset, sqlQuery, CRecordset::readOnly);
return records;
}
```

The error i get:

```
error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'
```

Comment: The compiler answered that question for you, that is an unambiguous NO!  The error message isn't the greatest, but it googles Really Well.

Comment: On a side note, `records.m_pDatabase` will be a dangling pointer after `ExecuteSqlQuery` returns, because `database` is a local variable that gets destroyed on return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CObject` is a non-copyable class. The copy c'tor is made private so as to prevent copying.

Since `CRecordset` inherits from `CObject` and doesn't provide its own copy constructor. It's not copyable either. Returning by value requires the presence of a copy (or move) constructor.

So your only recourse is to either use an "output parameter"; have the caller pass the `CRecordset` that `ExecuteSqlQuery` should populated:

```
void COrderSearch::ExecuteSqlQuery(CString query, CRecordset& outRecords) {
  // populate outRecords
}
```

Or return a smart pointer to a `CRecordset`.